# How to use non ascii characters in CMake add_executable

Tags: c++, cmake

For example, in `CmakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable( ❤ test.cpp )
```

Will cause:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:37 (add_executable):
  The target name "❤" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake features,
  such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined behavior.
```

I think useing non-ascii characters today is quite simple, how to make CMake support that?

Comment: Such characters are not allowed as per CMake policy [CMP0037](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0037.html): "Target names may contain upper and lower case letters, numbers, the underscore character (_), dot(.), plus(+) and minus(-)."

Comment: @CherryDT, thanks a lot, I can not believe this restriction is still exists in 2021...

Comment: In fact, it doesn't _still_ exist, it was _added_ in CMake 3.0 in June 2014!

Comment: What's your goal here?  Are you trying to make an executable named `❤`?

Comment: @StephenNewell, `❤` is just an example, but in real project I have several sub-directories and need executable based on directory names. Thus I do not want to change every sub project's name.

Comment: @CherryDT, Yes, you inspired me by 2014, maybe `cmake_policy(OLD)` will work here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options are limited with what you can use as target names, but you have much more flexibility with the `OUTPUT_NAME` property.

Working example:

```
add_executable(heart test.cpp)
set_target_properties(heart PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME ❤
)
```

Output:

```
$ make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/heart.dir/test.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ❤
[100%] Built target heart
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this properties is really what I want!